# Print every step of merge sort in C

Tags: c, mergesort, array-merge

Some I am pretty new to C code and I would like to know how do I do about printing every step of the merge sort.

For example, my unsorted array is (2, 9, 4, 6, 8, 5}. Then I want to print out `First Half is 2, 9, 4`and then `Second half is 6, 8, 5`.

Then sort each half, and print `First half sorted is 2, 4, 9` and `Second half sorted is 5, 6, 8`.

Finally show the sorted list `Sorted array is 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9`

Here is my code:

```
//Splitting the array into 2
void merge(int arr[], int lhs, int mid, int rhs) {
int i, j, k;
int half1 = mid - lhs + 1;
int half2 = rhs - mid;

int first[half1], second[half2]; //Temporary arrays

for (i = 0; i < half1; i++) {
    first[i] = arr[lhs + i];
}

for (j = 0; j < half2; j++) {
    second[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];
}

i = 0;
j = 0;
k = lhs;

while (i < half1 && j < half2) {

    if (first[i] <= second[j]) {
        arr[k] = first[i];
        ++i;
    } else {
        arr[k] = second[j];
        j++;
    }

    k++;
}

while (i < half1) {
    arr[k] = first[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

while (j < half2) {
    arr[k] = second[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
}


//Merge Sorting
void merge_sort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
if (l < r) {
    int midd = (l + (r-1))/ 2;
    merge_sort(arr, l, midd);
    merge_sort(arr, midd+1, r);
    merge(arr, l, midd, r);
   }
}
```

Comment: So you are asking which function is used to print in C?

Comment: ^^^^^ yeah, just printf stuff out.

Comment: Basically, like which to print. I used `printf("%d", first[i])` for the first half and it giving me weird numbers.

Comment: That more likely than not means you are attempting to access array members **outside the bounds** of the array, *or*, your arrays passed to `merge` are not properly initialized, *or* the bounds you pass as `lhs`, `mid`, `rhs` are incorrect. (obviously the `printf` syntax is correct, so the values are the problem). Additionally, avoid `printf` for a single char, use, e.g. `putchar ('\n');` instead. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).